# Why does std::bind give errors when using icc 14.01 with gcc 4.8?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, icc, odeint

I have a problem compiling this short piece of code:

UPDATED:
I have a much simpler code fragment that produces the same error now, the old one can still be seen at the end of the post.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Bar {

public:
  void foo(double x, double y) {
      std::cout << x << std::endl;
      std::cout << y << std::endl;
  }

  void foo2(double x) {
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    auto function = std::bind(&Bar::foo, this, x, _1);
    function(3);
  }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Bar bar;
  bar.foo2(3);
}
```

I have one computer where it compiles fine:

```
openSUSE 12.3 with gcc 4.7.2 20130108, icc 14.0.1 20131008, boost 1_49
```

On this computer both

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

and

```
icc main.cpp -std=c++11
```

work.

On another computer with

```
openSUSE 13.1 with gcc 4.8.1 20130909 , icc 14.0.1 20131008, boost 1_54


g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

works, but

```
icc main.cpp -std=c++11
```

results in the following error message:

```
main2.cpp(17): error: no instance of overloaded function "std::_Bind<_Functor (_Bound_args...)>::operator() [with _Functor=std::_Mem_fn<double (Bar::*)(double, double)>, _Bound_args=<Bar *, double, std::_Placeholder<1>>]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int)
            object type is: std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<double (Bar::*)(double, double)> (Bar *, double, std::_Placeholder<1>)>
      function(3);
```

OLD CODE:

```
#include <vector>

#include "boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/runge_kutta4.hpp"

using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
typedef std::vector<double> state_type;

class Right_Hand_Side {
public:
  void operator()(const state_type &y, state_type &y_dot, const double t)
  {}

};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  Right_Hand_Side right_hand_side;
  std::vector<double> state(10);
  runge_kutta4<state_type> stepper;
  stepper.do_step( std::ref(right_hand_side), state, 0, 0.1); 

}
```

error message:

```
XXX/include/boost/numeric/odeint/util/resizer.hpp(72): error: no instance of overloaded function "std::_Bind<_Functor (_Bound_args...)>::operator() [with _Functor=std::_Mem_fn<bool (boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, (unsigned short)4U,
          state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>::*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> &)>, _Bound_args=<std::reference_wrapper<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations,
          boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, (unsigned short)4U, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>>, std::_Placeholder<1>>]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>)
            object type is: std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, (unsigned short)4U, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations,
                      boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>::*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> &)> (std::reference_wrapper<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, (unsigned short)4U, state_type, double, state_type, double,
                      boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>>, std::_Placeholder<1>)>
              return f( x );
                     ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "bool boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer::adjust_size(const State &, ResizeFunction) [with State=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>, ResizeFunction=std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, (unsigned
                      short)4U, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>::*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> &)> (std::reference_wrapper<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra,
                      boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, (unsigned short)4U, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>>, std::_Placeholder<1>)>]" at line 196 of "XXX//include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/base/explicit_stepper_base.hpp"
            instantiation of "void boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::do_step_v1(System, StateInOut &, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type) [with
                      Stepper=boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, Order=(unsigned short)4U, State=state_type, Value=double, Deriv=state_type, Time=double, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer,
                      System=std::reference_wrapper<Right_Hand_Side>, StateInOut=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>]" at line 113 of "XXX//include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/base/explicit_stepper_base.hpp"
            instantiation of "void boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::do_step(System, StateInOut &, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type) [with
                      Stepper=boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, Order=(unsigned short)4U, State=state_type, Value=double, Deriv=state_type, Time=double, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer,
                      System=std::reference_wrapper<Right_Hand_Side>, StateInOut=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>]" at line 21 of "main.cpp"

XXX//include/boost/numeric/odeint/util/resizer.hpp(72): error: no instance of overloaded function "std::_Bind<_Functor (_Bound_args...)>::operator() [with _Functor=std::_Mem_fn<bool (boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>::*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> &)>,
          _Bound_args=<std::reference_wrapper<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>>, std::_Placeholder<1>>]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>)
            object type is: std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>::*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> &)> (std::reference_wrapper<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra,
                      boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>>, std::_Placeholder<1>)>
              return f( x );
                     ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "bool boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer::adjust_size(const State &, ResizeFunction) [with State=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>, ResizeFunction=std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>::*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>
                      &)> (std::reference_wrapper<boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>>, std::_Placeholder<1>)>]" at line 146 of "XXX//include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/explicit_generic_rk.hpp"
            instantiation of "void boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<StageCount, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::do_step_impl(System, const StateIn &, const DerivIn &, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<StageCount, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type, StateOut &, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<StageCount, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type) [with
                      StageCount=4UL, Order=4UL, State=state_type, Value=double, Deriv=state_type, Time=double, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, System=std::reference_wrapper<Right_Hand_Side>, StateIn=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>, DerivIn=state_type, StateOut=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>]" at line 198 of
                      "XXX//include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/base/explicit_stepper_base.hpp"
            instantiation of "void boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::do_step_v1(System, StateInOut &, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type) [with
                      Stepper=boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, Order=(unsigned short)4U, State=state_type, Value=double, Deriv=state_type, Time=double, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer,
                      System=std::reference_wrapper<Right_Hand_Side>, StateInOut=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>]" at line 113 of "XXX//include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/base/explicit_stepper_base.hpp"
            instantiation of "void boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::do_step(System, StateInOut &, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_stepper_base<Stepper, Order, State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type) [with
                      Stepper=boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_generic_rk<4UL, 4UL, state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, Order=(unsigned short)4U, State=state_type, Value=double, Deriv=state_type, Time=double, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::range_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer,
                      System=std::reference_wrapper<Right_Hand_Side>, StateInOut=std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>]" at line 21 of "main.cpp"

compilation aborted for main.cpp (code 2)
```

I have a feeling this is nothing boost::odeint specific, but rather a weird compiler issue that comes up when using std::bind, std::function etc. (this is true see new code at top of post)

Comment: Those ICC version numbers don't look right?

Comment: Are the boost versions the same? what are they?

Comment: @TristanBrindle: the dangers of copy and paste. corrected the icc versions

Comment: @Silex: added boost versions to post

Comment: which odeint version do you use? the latest one from https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2 ?

Comment: yes odeint-v2, but really the problem does not seem to be related to boost at all, see updated post

Comment: We had a similar problem with icc and std::bind in our repo in December, but it has been fixed and should we work now for icc. But maybe you should look at some icc related mailings list, bug tracker if they have problems with their standard library and std::bind.

Comment: I am also having this problem with icc 14.0.2. I will post this problem on the Intel forums and then provide a link here.

Comment: I have posted this problem on the Intel forums [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/505628).

Answer (score 2):

I posted this issue on the Intel forums [here](http://software.intel.com/comment/1780290) and got the following response:

> Thanks for reporting it!
>
> We've been working on it and it's been tracked as DPD200242895. Will update you when the fix is available. There is no easy workaround for this. Sorry about that.

It seems that they are aware of the problem and are working on a solution. Hopefully the next update/release will correct this.

**UPDATE:**

This problem has been fixed in version 14.0 update 3 and later:

> This issue is fixed in 14.0 update 3 and later, as well as 15.0.
>
> Thanks,
> Jennifer